# Variation of the dining philosophers: is the standard solution still valid?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization

I have a problem that is almost equal to the standard one of the dining philosophers, but has a quirk: while a philosopher thinks, he still holds the fork on his left.

If after the period of thinking (which isn't infinite), I release the fork on the left and then apply the normal solution (that is, acquire forks in the order of their [priority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution)), then would this solution be correct for this problem?

Comment: When finished eating, are both forks released (so before thinking the left one has to be re-acquired)? or does the philosopher hold on to the left fork, only releasing the right one (so thinking starts immediately)?

Answer (score 1):

If the philosopher eats (holding both forks), drops the right fork and thinks for a while, and then drops the left fork to take a nap (or something similar), it is just the original problem: Each philosopher must ensure getting both forks without deadlock. Take a look at Allen B. Downey's ["The Little Book on Semaphores"](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) for in-depth discussion (this problem is *hard*!).